# xdocreport failed to process template and generate PDF

Tags: java, pdf, xdocreport

I have problem with generating pdf from odt file using opensagres/xdocreport
 library.
process() method call fails with NPE. Short research shows that there is not template engine in XDocReportEscapeReference.setRuntimeServices(). Can anyone help me to understand what is wrong with this code and can recommend me other simple library to generate pdf from template?

```
ITemplateEngine templateEngine = (ITemplateEngine) rs.getProperty( VELOCITY_TEMPLATE_ENGINE_KEY );
```

Here is my test project:

```
        IXDocReport template = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(resource.getInputStream(), TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);
        Options options = Options.getTo(ConverterTypeTo.PDF).via(ConverterTypeVia.ODFDOM);

        IContext context = template.createContext();
        context.put("a", "test A");
        context.put("b", "test B);

        template.convert(context, options, stream);
```

Error msg:

```
fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.XDocReportException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity.internal.VelocityTemplateEngine.initializeVelocityEngine(VelocityTemplateEngine.java:136)
at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity.internal.VelocityTemplateEngine.getVelocityEngine(VelocityTemplateEngine.java:118)
at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity.internal.VelocityTemplateEngine.processWithCache(VelocityTemplateEngine.java:96)
at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.AbstractTemplateEngine.process(AbstractTemplateEngine.java:112)
at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.AbstractTemplateEngine.process(AbstractTemplateEngine.java:83)
at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.AbstractXDocReport.processTemplateEngine(AbstractXDocReport.java:775)
at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.AbstractXDocReport.convert(AbstractXDocReport.java:703)
at ee.maksekeskus.backoffice.services.impl.ReportServiceImpl.generateMerchantContactReport(ReportServiceImpl.java:47)
at ee.maksekeskus.backoffice.services.impl.ReportServiceImlTest.testReportGeneration(ReportServiceImlTest.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity.internal.XDocReportEscapeReference.setRuntimeServices(XDocReportEscapeReference.java:56)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeSpecificEventHandler(RuntimeInstance.java:712)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeEventHandlers(RuntimeInstance.java:626)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:243)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:534)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.init(VelocityEngine.java:144)
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity.internal.VelocityTemplateEngine.initializeVelocityEngine

Comment: Have you check you are using the same Velocity version than XDocReport samples?

Comment: as I understood xdocreport contain own velocity dependencies

Comment: No, why do you say that? XDocReport is based on Velocity 1.7 https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/blob/master/template/fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity/pom.xml Perhaps it works with other versions, I don't know.

Comment: As Angelo said, you need the right version of Velocity. Please share the dependency/import/task... section of your pom or gradle file, so we can see if there are any problems there